# Inserting filename in database

Tags: codeigniter, special-characters, plupload, non-ascii-characters

I am using plupload with codeigniter to upload files.

But when the filename have special characters it has problem.

Example: when the filename is "cópia" its insert "co?pia"

I have to insert the original filename in DB and declare 'UTF-8' in aplication

Someone can help?

---

EDIT: The problem is the field is on latin1 and my application is on UTF-8.. If I convert the field, can I have problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use $this->security->sanitize_filename() to remove invalid filenames before inserting the data to DB

More information can be found here
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/security.html

To declare UTF-8 you need to modify
application/config/database.php

$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

Comment: My database equal this

Answer (score 0):

two parts:

1, your reader. 
make sure your reader(could be your coded program) is on UTF8

2, your database also on UTF8  ,
 for  MS-SQL server the column should be `nvarchar()`

Comment: Thats in the database the problem. The table is on UTF-8, but the field encoding is on latin1. Have any suggestion?

Comment: what's your data engine ? should be easy to google like 'mySQL latin1 to UTF8'

Comment: My engine is innoDB. The problem the table is really giant. It will be harder convert this to UTF-8

Comment: for giant, i will create a fresh new table or column, then write a small program to populate it chunk by chunk, otherwise you may get kind of transaction log problem.